# Navegador me da este error "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 al intentar subir una imagen

Tags: laravel, angular

Mi objetivo es hacer mi llamada a mi api para subir una imagen en la base de datos al hacer clic al botón subir desde Angular.
Pero al realizar clic en el navegador me salta este error.

```
**"message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'imagen' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2022-04-01 09:24:42, 2022-04-01 09:24:42))",**;
```

Mi código de mi migración. He solucionado el error ya que me faltaba el paréntesis de **nullable** pero ahora el problema que a la base de datos da respuestas pero solo me llega al campo imagen NULL y no la imagen.

```
**2022_03_31_185512_create_posts_table
 **public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->binary('imagen')->nullable(); 
        $table->timestamps();
    });
};**
```

Mi modelo se ve así.

```
class Post extends Model{use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = [
    'imagen'];}
```

En el controlador tengo una función para subir la imagen.

```
public function uploadguardar(Request $request){
    $post = new Post();
   
    //script para subir imagen 
    if ($request->hasFile("imagen")){
      $completeFileName = $request->file('imagen')->getClientOriginalName();
      $fileNameOnly = pathinfo($completeFileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
      $extenshion = $request->file('imagen')->getclientOriginalExtension();
      $compPic = str_replace("", "_", $fileNameOnly). "-".rand() . "_".time(). ",".$extenshion;
        $path = $request->file('imagen')->storeAs('public/posts', $compPic);
       $post->imagen = $compPic;
       
    } 
    if($post->save())
    {
        return ['status' => true, 'menssage' => 'enviado todo ok'];
    } else {
        return ['status' => false, 'menssage' => 'error no enviado'];
    }
    
}
```

Mi función en Angular lo que he notado que la palabra subscribe me sale tachado.

```
subirArchivo(): any {
try {
  this.loading = true;
  const formularioDeDatos = new FormData();
  this.archivos.forEach((archivo: string ) => {
    formularioDeDatos.append('files', archivo);
  });
  // formularioDeDatos.append('_id', 'MY_ID_123')
  this.rest.post(`http://localhost:8000/api/Uploadguardar`, formularioDeDatos)
  .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.loading = false;
        console.log('Respuesta del servidor', res);
      },() => {
        this.loading = false;
        alert('ERROR');
      });
} catch (e) {
  this.loading = false;
  console.log("error")
  console.log('ERROR', e);
}
```

};

Mi HTML en Angular donde se ve el botón enviar.

```
div class="wrapper">
<div class="position-relative">
    <h3>Subir imagen</h3>
    <input class="input-file" (change)="capturarFile($event)" type="file">
    <div class="preview-img" *ngIf="previsualizacion">
        <button class="clear-image" type="button" (click)="clearImage()">Clear</button>
        <img  [src]="previsualizacion" alt="">
    </div>
  
    <div class="p-1">
        <small>Se aceptan archivos imágenes de tipo .png</small>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-button" *ngIf="previsualizacion">
        <button type="button" class="button" [disabled]="loading" (click)="subirArchivo()">
            {{(loading) ? 'Cargando.....' : 'Subir Archivo'}}
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: es nullable();
 no nullable, y claro que no te guarda nada pues la parte del sql indica que no estas guardando la imagen, falta el codigo del controlador donde recives las variables y las pasas al modelo para guardar

Comment: He modificado ya se puede ver el controlador que no subí el código pero tengo mi función creada la cual funciona correctamente. Ya me di cuenta que al poner nullable() si da respuestas pero en la base de datos no me llega la imagen solo Null.

Comment: asegurate que en tu form admita imagenes enctype='multipart/form-data

Comment: parece que si admite imagenes Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="subirarchivoangular.png"
Content-Type: image/png esto me sale en el navegador en red.

Comment: En el controlador imprime los valores del post y file para ver si llega lo que envias

Comment: Cuando trabajas con archivos la variable es file no post, sin el código del controlador es difícil **adivinar** lo que estás haciendo

Comment: La función esta probado con Postman y las imágenes llegan correctamente y se guardan en la carpeta indicada. Lo que sospecho que el error debe estar en el front.